# Form Field Dependency Not Triggered When Value Changed Dynamically Magento 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento-1.9

Using Magento 1.9 `->addFieldDependence`method, my related field value is changed dynamically therefore the magento field dependence method is not triggered.

I tried jquery `$j("#meter_type_code").trigger("change");` to force the onchange  event and trigger the Magento dependence function to no avail.

Relevant excerpt of my code:

```
<script>
    var metertype = <?php echo $meter_type; ?>; //$metertype is an array
</script>

$fieldset->addField('meter_type_code', 'text', array( //set to text for testing will be hidden
    'name'  => 'machine.meter_type_code',

$fieldset->addField('meter_type', 'select', array(
    'label'     => 'Meter Type',
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
    'required'  => true,
    'name'      => 'machine.meter_type',
    'onchange'  => 'changeFieldValue(metertype[this.value]);trigger();',
    'values'    => Mage::getModel('machinemanager/machine_metertype')->getMeterTypes($attributeSetName),
    'disabled'  => false,
    'readonly'  => false,
    'after_element_html' => '</br><small>Time in service</small>',
    'tabindex'  => 1
    ))
    ->setAfterElementHtml('
        <script>
            function changeFieldValue(value) {                                              
                document.getElementById("meter_type_code").value = value;
            }
            function trigger(value) {
                //this is where I tried various methods to trigger the event none of which had effect to fire the Magento field dependence
            }

        </script>
    ');
$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
    ->addFieldMap('meter_type_code','meter_type_code')
    ->addFieldMap('meter_type','meter_type')
    ->addFieldMap('time', 'time')
    ->addFieldMap('time_adjust', 'time_adjust')
    ->addFieldMap('cycles', 'cycles')
    ->addFieldMap('cycles_adjust', 'cycles_adjust')
    ->addFieldDependence('time', 'meter_type_code', array('t','tc'))
    ->addFieldDependence('time_adjust', 'meter_type_code', array('t','tc'))
    ->addFieldDependence('cycles', 'meter_type_code', array('c','tc'))
    ->addFieldDependence('cycles_adjust', 'meter_type_code', array('c','tc'))
);
```

When I successfully forced the onchange event using jquery, nothing happened until I actually retyped the value of meter_type_code and caused a real keyboard action.  That triggered the magento javascript to make the dependent fields appear and disappear perfectly.

Can anyone tell me how to cause the addFieldDependence to trigger when the target field of the dependency is dynamically updated from another field?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!  [Thanks to Mirasvit Extensions](https://mirasvit.com/blog/dynamic-showhide-of-data-fields-in-magento.html)

This trigger works:

```
function trigger(value) {
    // $j("#meter_type_code").trigger("change");
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); 
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true); 
    document.getElementById("meter_type_code").dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

I commented out the JQuery method that did trigger a change event, but did not cause the Magento dependency method to work.  I'd be interested in any comments why the JQuery trigger would not work in this case.